# OpenCV cv::getStructuringElement with CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE produces a black square

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to perform a dilation on my image and want to use a disc for the dilation operation. But whatever I am trying, I always end up getting a black square:

```
dilSize = 12;
kern = cv::getStructuringElement( CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE, cv::Size( dilSize + 1, dilSize + 1 ) );

cv::dilate( im, im, kern, cv::Point( -1, -1 ), 10 );
cv::imwrite( "ker.png", ker );
```

The result is a 13x13 pixel black square in the PNG image...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `cv::getStructuringElement` just creates zeros and ones, there is no optical difference.

Adding:

```
kernel *= 255;
```

before writing the image, solves the mystery ;)